# Is there a way to rewrite this apparently simple Django snippet so that it doesn't hit the database so much?

Tags: django, performance, generic-foreign-key

I have a class called `ToggleProperty`. I use it to store information about whether a use toggled some properties on an object. Examples of properties are "like", "bookmark" and "follow".

```
class ToggleProperty(models.Model):
    # "like", "bookmark", "follow" etc
    property_type = CharField()

    # The user who toggled the property
    user = ForeignKey(User)

    # The object upon which the user is toggling the property, e.g. "user likes image"
    object_id = models.TextField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Now, I'd like to get a list of users that are followed by a certain other user, let's call him Tom.

I can't just query on `ToggleProperty`, because that would give me ToggleProperties, not Users!

So I do this:

```
# First get the ContentType for user, we'll need it
user_ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(User)

# Now get the users that Tom follows
followed_by_tom = [
    user_ct.get_object_for_this_type(id = x.object_id) for x in   
    ToggleProperty.objects.filter(
        property_type = "follow",
        user = tom,
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(User))
]
```

The problem with this is that it hits the database in my view, and I don't like that.

If this wasn't ugly enough, hear me out. I'm actually interested in the images uploaded by the users that Tom follows, so I can show Tom all the images by the people he follows.

So to the code above, I add this:

```
images = Image.objects.filter(user__in = followed_by_tom)
```

This ends up performing over 400 queries, and taking over a second to process. There has to be a better way, could you please show me the path?

Answer (score 2):

This piece:

```
followed_by_tom = [
user_ct.get_object_for_this_type(id = x.object_id) for x in   
ToggleProperty.objects.filter(
    property_type = "follow",
    user = tom,
    content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(User))
]
```

gets all of the `User` instances which are followed in `N` queries when it could be done in a single query. In fact you don't need the instances themselves only the ids to get the `Images` with the `IN` query. So you can remove the extra queries in the loop via:

```
followed_by_tom = ToggleProperty.objects.filter(
    property_type="follow",
    user=tom,
    content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(User)
).values_list('object_id', flat=True)

images = Image.objects.filter(user__in=followed_by_tom)
```

Since `followed_by_tom` is never evaluated the ORM should execute this as a single query with a sub-select.

Comment: followed_by_tom should have users list right? but you would get list of object_ids. How is it working?

Comment: The point is you don't need the list of Users. You only need the list of ids.